# How to obtain the promise value inside loop outsdie the Promise to increment another value?

Tags: typescript, protractor, angular-promise

I am trying to obtain the rows of table:
And i am getting a count of rows :
i need to get the value returned by promise and increment another value:
a + rowCountWhile > which is in while loop in same function.
Not able to get the value  of rowCountWhile to increment

```
public  getRowCount(webTableElement:ElementArrayFinder,totalcount:ElementFinder){
    let finalTotal
    let totalslice
    let finalrowCount
    let rowCountWhile1
    totalcount.getText().then(function(total){
        console.log("total:"+total)
        totalslice = total.slice(15);
        finalTotal = parseInt(totalslice);
        console.log("final total:"+finalTotal);

    let countrows = webTableElement.count().then(function(rowCount){

    console.log("tr count:"+rowCount)
    finalrowCount = rowCount;
    console.log("Final RowCount:"+finalrowCount)
    while(finalrowCount<finalTotal)
    {
        console.log("Test"+finalrowCount)
        provisioningToolPage.superBranchIDNextNavigator.click();
        return webTableElement.count().then(function(rowCountWhile){
        console.log("Promise value:"+rowCountWhile)
        rowCountWhile1 = rowCountWhile;
        return rowCountWhile1
    })

       console.log("outside promise:"+rowCountWhile1)
       //finalrowCount = finalrowCount + rowcountwhile;
       //console.log("rowCountWhile:"+finalrowCount1)
       finalrowCount= finalrowCount + 10;
    }
    })
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Focus on the code:

```
while(finalrowCount<finalTotal)
    {
        console.log("Test"+finalrowCount)
        provisioningToolPage.superBranchIDNextNavigator.click();
        return webTableElement.count().then(function(rowCountWhile){
        console.log("Promise value:"+rowCountWhile)
        rowCountWhile1 = rowCountWhile;
        return rowCountWhile1
    })

       console.log("outside promise:"+rowCountWhile1)
       //finalrowCount = finalrowCount + rowcountwhile;
       //console.log("rowCountWhile:"+finalrowCount1)
       finalrowCount= finalrowCount + 10;
    }
    })
```

You are mixing `while` with a `Promise`. What will happen is that *all* the `while` statements will execute *before* the first promise resolves.

## Fix

Easiest fix would be to make your code execution order sequential by using `async/await` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Thank you.. but i am new to typescript andi still dont understand this.Can you help me out taking my example above please